# How to move unknown files to unknown directories based on folder name?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, find

I am trying to write a script that will search a directory for a folder, and move the folders contents one directory up from their location. this is what i have so far:

```
find ./localFolders -name 'file' -type d -exec mv {}/* .. \;
```

I think my problem lies in the destination directory of `..`. perhaps I am expressing this wrong?

Any help is useful.

****edit*****

to simplify this ill go into more info

I am with an organization that it attempting to move from MS Exchange to Zimbra. As part of our migration we have found great utilities that transfer mailboxes but transferring PST files to Zimbra usable format is proving challenging.

I have found some solutions though to make a long story short, I have been able to spin out pst files to a usable format with one exception –

instead of putting the mail in that folder a sub directory is created called `“mbox”` presumably resembling the mbox file that the .eml files are being broken out from. Because each user is different and uses different folder structures from other users, each directory is unknown until the script runs. Additionally the contents of the mbox folder are also unique.

Because the folder named mbox is the only constant in these directories I am trying to use find to locate those folders take that folders contents and move them up one directory, then delete the folder named mbox. Here is the actual command as it appears in my script:

```
find localFolders -name mbox -type d -exec mv {}/* .. \;
```

or in the example you just gave:

```
find localFolders -name mbox -type d -execdir sh -c 'echo mv {}/* ..' \;
```

I am trying to use the `*` as a wildcard to select everything in the mbox folder . As best as I can tell it is instead being treated as part of the directory, and not the wildcard as intended

thoughts?

Comment: And have you seen my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
find ./localFolders -name 'file' -type d -execdir bash -c 'mv -vnt . -- "$0"/*' {} \; -prune
```

Safe regarding spaces and funny symbols in filenames. Enjoy!

Comment: cool this seems to have worked! curious, what was the point behind using prune? played around and experimented with it, i didn't see any change when removing that argument.

Comment: `-prune` might not be very useful in your case, but it prevents `find` to go inside the directory `file` and try to further find other directories named `file`. It's a good optimization in case you have a big dir tree inside `file`. (I hope this is clear enough).

Answer (score 1):

In order to do what you want correctly using `find` you have to understand the following concepts:

1. The working directory of a process.
2. The glob feature of bash (or other shells).

Every process in linux has a working directory as part of its internal state. You can imagine it as the "location" of the process in the filesystem. The shell is also a process and also has a working directory. The working directory of the shell is the directory (usually) displayed in your prompt.

When a process is created it will inherit the working directory from its parent. If you start a process from the shell then the shell is the parent. Every process can change its own working directory at will. You can change the working directory of the shell using the builtin command `cd`.

The working directory is used when dealing with relative filenames. Relative filenames are filenames that do not start with `/`. For example when you do `cat foo` it will look for the file `foo` in the current working directory, but when you do `cat /tmp/foo` it will look for the file `foo` in `/tmp`.

When dealing with `find -exec` you always have to think about the working directory. The working directory of `-exec` is the working directory of `find`. The working directory of `find` is the working directory of the shell.

In your case:

```
find ./localFolders -name 'file' -type d -exec mv {}/* .. \;
```

The `..` will reference to the parent directory of the working directory of `mv` which is the working directory of `-exec` which is the the working directory of `find` which is the working directory of the shell by the time you executed the command. That is not what you wanted.

There is an `-execdir` which is like `-exec` but it first switches the working directory to the directory where the matching item is found. `-execdir` is a huge step towards the solution to your question, but there is another problem in your `find` command: the `*` a.k.a. glob.

A glob is something like a wildcard. For example `foo*` will match `foobar` and `foobaz` (and `foo` because `*` also matches the null string). So far so good. The interesting part of globbing is that it is done by the shell, not by the executed command. When you execute `rm foo*` then the shell will first expand the `*` to `foobar` and `foobaz` and then execute `rm foobar foobaz`. `rm` never sees the `*`.

What happens when there are no files starting with `foo` in the current directory? Then the shell (usually) will not expand the `*` and will pass the `*` to the command in verbatim. That means `rm foo*` will be executed as `rm foo*`. `rm` will look for a file named `foo*` and it will (most likely) not find one and abort with an error. In case you are wondering: yes it is possible for a filename to contain `*`, no don't try that at home.

In your case:

```
find ./localFolders -name 'file' -type d -exec mv {}/* .. \;
```

Before executing the `find` command the shell will first try to expand the glob `{}/*`. There are no files matching the pattern `{}/*` so the glob will be passed verbatim.

Let's see what the `find` command does. Suppose you are executing the `find` command from `/home/username/somedir` and there exists a directory `/home/username/somedir/localFolders/foodir/file` with some files in it. `find` will start searching in `/home/username/somedir/localFolders` because it is told so in the parameters but the working directory of `find` is `/home/username/somedir` because it was executed from there.

Now `find` found the directory `/home/username/somedir/localFolders/foodir/file`. Before it executes the `-exec` it will replace the `{}` with the found item. That means `mv {}/* ..` will become `mv /home/username/somedir/localFolders/foodir/file/* ..`. `mv` will fail because it will (most likely) not find a file named `*`.

Suppose there is a file named `*` then `mv` will move the file to `..`. Remember that the working directory is `/home/username/somedir`. That means `mv` will move the file to `/home/username/somedir/..` which is `/home/username`. That is not what you wanted.

The "fix" for your `find` command depends on several factors. For example:

- Are there "dotfiles" in the `file` directory? Dotfiles are files with names starting with a dot. The `*` glob will (usually) not expand to filenames starting with a dot.
- Are there other directories in the `file` directory? `find` will try to recurse in to them but fail because they have been moved.
- Are there directories named `file` in the `file` directory? Where should those files go?
- Are there a gazillion files in the `file` directory? That might mess up the `*` glob expansion.
- Are there filename collisions with files out of the `file` directory? Should they be overwritten?
- Are there spaces in the filenames? That will mess everything up.

To fix your `find` command I will happily ignore all those factors.

Here is a fix using `-execdir` and `sh -c` to delay the expansion of `*`:

```
find ./localFolders -name file -type d -execdir sh -c 'mv {}/* ..' \;
```

Since the `*` is in quotes it will not get expanded ahead of time. When `-execdir` executes the command then `sh -c` will expand the `*` in the working directory.

Here is another fix without `sh -c`:

```
find ./localFolders -path "*/file/*" -execdir mv {} .. \;
```

I used `-path` to find all items under directories with the name `file`. The `*` are in quotes so they will not get expanded ahead of time. This time `find` takes care of the interpretation of the `*`. Note that this will also match something like `./localFolders/foodir/file/bardir/file/somefile`. As said I happily ignored that factor.

And for the sake of completeness another fix without `-execdir`:

```
find ./localFolders -name file -type d -exec sh -c 'mv {}/* {}/..' \;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. 

Both of these commands failed 

-execdir failed with mv: cannot stat `./file/*' : No such file or directory

The full command that I used was:

find ./localFolders -name 'file' -type d -execdir mv {}/* . \;

Comment: see updated answer

Comment: please see the edits to my original post

Comment: @Don, I made a mistake earlier. I forgot to remove the `echo` in the `sh -c` commands. I now removed the `echo`. Please try again without the `echo`.

Comment: after reattempting this, the issue remains unaffected. the terminal apears to complete, but the mbox folders remain with all of the email still inside. FYI right now this has become a point of curiosity, as I have been able to solve this issue with a php script. please post if anything is found that might work. I would rather keep a uniform CLI solution w/out using different programming languages, but im finding this issue to be a stubborn one